# Generate unique JS script names during development of Angular app

Tags: angular

I'm developing an Angular 6 app and the development needs to occur in a very custom browser with a very agressive cache policy that I can't change.

The problem is that the browser caches the `runtime.js`, `main.js`, etc...

I know that I can use `ng serve --prod` to let Angular generate unique script names like `runtime.a79af62d1feed345ccb6.js` which solves my caching problem but it's also very slow.

So the question is:

**Is there a way to activate the generation of unique script names without the disadvantages of the `--prod` option?**

Maybe via the `angular.json` file.

Comment: angular cli automatically takes care of cache busting when using development mode. you do not need to do anything. are runtime.js and main.js your files or the frameworks? if the frameworks files then they won't be changed so no need to generate uniqure file names for them

Comment: `runtime.js`, `polyfill.js`, `styles.js`, `vendor.js` and `main.js` are the JS files generated by the framework. Yeah I know that usually angular cli takes care of that, but in this situation development happens through a reverse proxy, and in a particular environment, among other things. And the reloading and cache busting isn't working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a way.

I added the `"outputHashing": "all"` property in the `projects` > `my-app` > `architect` > `build` part of the `angular.json` file.

```
{
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
            "src/favicon.png",
            "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
            "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
            "src/scss/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "outputHashing": "all" <--- Relevant line
    },
    "configurations": { ... },
}
```